# UISwitch setSelected not working?

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch

I'm trying to set the UISwitch selected value and it's not responding!

**Here is my code**

I set the value to UISwitch. Default value is False.

```
[mailSwitch setSelected:TRUE];
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Just made the same mistake. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The property you’re looking for is `on`; in method form, `-setOn:` or `-setOn:animated:`.

`selected` is a generic property, declared on UIControl, which has no visible effect on a UISwitch.

Answer (score 3):

Would be something like this

```
[mailswitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

setOn should work

When I developed an iPhone App, I had problems with checking the status of a checkbox, too. My workaround was to call a function everytime this checkbos is selected or deselected, and save the status then in another variable.